# React Apollo default fetchPolicy

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

How do I set a global default fetchPolicy for my react app? I want cache-and-network to be my default. I've tried:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: headerResponseReader.concat(link),
  defaultOptions: { query: { fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network" } }
});
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hate to be the bearer of bad news here.... I did find why it isn't working. Line 247 is why, you can't have a default cache-and-network on non-watch queries.. This link takes you to the lines: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/455d3b7ed1843226961040c4cea79a4c165dcc74/packages/apollo-client/src/ApolloClient.ts#L238

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I correctly type the Apollo Client defaultOptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472440/how-do-i-correctly-type-the-apollo-client-defaultoptions)

Answer (score 1):

[For the time being](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2555#issuecomment-449871538) you have to set all three types.

```
const defaultOptions = { 
  watchQuery: {
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
    errorPolicy: 'ignore',
  },
  query: {
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  },
  mutate: {
    errorPolicy: 'all'
  }
}

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache,
  defaultOptions,
})
```

Comment: `cache-and-network` is not accepted for query.