# How do I correctly type the Apollo Client defaultOptions?

Tags: typescript, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm setting up Apollo Client like this.

```js
const defaultOptions = {
  watchQuery: {
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
    errorPolicy: 'ignore',
  },
  query: {
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  },
  mutate: {
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  },
};
return new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([authLink, errorLink, webSocketOrHttpLink]),
  defaultOptions, // Typescript don't like this.
  queryDeduplication: true,
});
```

Typescript gives this error:

```sh
Type '{ watchQuery: { fetchPolicy: string; errorPolicy: string; }; query: { fetchPolicy: string; errorPolicy: string; }; mutate: { errorPolicy: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'DefaultOptions'.ts(2322)
ApolloClient.d.ts(23, 5): The expected type comes from property 'defaultOptions' which is declared here on type 'ApolloClientOptions<NormalizedCacheObject>'
```

Per the docs, [this](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client/#example-defaultoptions-object) is how it's supposed to be done.

How can I structure `defaultOptions` with proper types?

Comment: try defaultOptions: defaultOptions

Comment: @PranayRana No difference. 

Comment: hi , you are passing wrong value for fetchPolicy, check my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you check code of library then , it seems here is issue

```
//defination of default options
export interface DefaultOptions {
 watchQuery?: Partial<WatchQueryOptions>;
 query?: Partial<QueryOptions>;
 mutate?: Partial<MutationOptions>;  
}

//defination of QueryOptions
export interface QueryOptions<TVariables = OperationVariables>
  extends QueryBaseOptions<TVariables> {
  /**
   * Specifies the {@link FetchPolicy} to be used for this query
   */
  fetchPolicy?: FetchPolicy;
}

//valid value for FetchPolicy type 
export type FetchPolicy =
  | 'cache-first'
  | 'network-only'
  | 'cache-only'
  | 'no-cache'
  | 'standby';

export type WatchQueryFetchPolicy = FetchPolicy | 'cache-and-network';
```

so here for query options you should pass any valid value for `FetchPolicy` and `'cache-and-network'` is not valid value.

check documentation here :
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/main/src/core/watchQueryOptions.ts

Comment: That was it. I didn't even realize they now have different query types. Thanks! 
Guess I need to read the docs more often.  For anyone following along the query types are documented [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client/#apolloclient-functions).

Answer (score 3):

2021:

If you are trying to use `cache-and-network` as default for `query.fetchPolicy`:

The reason why `cache-and-network` is not allowed **intentionally** for `query` is explained back in 2019 here:
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3130#issuecomment-478409066

Basically, the behaviour/logic of `query()` is not supporting this strategy. So, they block it at typing level.

---

**React useQuery() hook**

And if you're using react, the `useQuery()` hook is following behaviour of `watchQuery` instead of `query`. So configuring the `watchQuery` is enough:

```
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  HttpLink,
  DefaultOptions
} from "@apollo/client";

const defaultOptions: DefaultOptions = {
  watchQuery: {
    fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
    errorPolicy: "ignore",
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true
  }
};
export const platformClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: "https://xxxxx",
    credentials: "same-origin"
  }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  defaultOptions
});
```